# How to properly type the theme passed as prop to the styled() method on Material UI? (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material UI with its styled function to stylize components, such as:

```
const MyThemeComponent = styled("div")(({ theme }) => `
  color: ${theme.palette.primary.contrastText};
  background-color: ${theme.palette.primary.main};
  padding: ${theme.spacing(1)};
  borderRadius: ${theme.shape.borderRadius};
`);
```

It works, but the typing does not, showing the fields, after written, as of type `any`. So, we're left without autocomplete, suggestions or error checking.

How can I have the typing working properly within the styled() method?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/themeusage-material-demo-forked-cm1ujx?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using the Emotion / Styled-Components format instead of the MUI format shown in the documentation.

```
const MyThemeComponent = styled("div")`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.primary.contrastText};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.primary.main};
  padding: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(2)};
  border-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.shape.borderRadius}px;
`;
```

[fixed demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/themeusage-material-demo-forked-yu3jff?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

does that work for you https://codesandbox.io/s/themeusage-material-demo-forked-pikixf.
I can't really test it properly if the autocomplete is working in the codesandbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. The editor suggestions indicate the only value `theme.palette` has is `mode` and `any` values.